# Ionic 3 - Sort Array By Another Array Pipe?

Tags: arrays, sorting, ionic-framework, ionic3, pipe

I need an ionic 3 Pipe that sort `Array1` by id using `OrderArray`.

#### HTML:

```
< ng-container *ngFor="let item of items | sortBy : ‘id’ >
```

#### `Array1`:

```
[
  {“id”: 1,“title”: “Post-1”,“thumb”: “post1.png”},    
  {“id”: 2,“title”: “Post-2”,“thumb”: “post2.png”},    
  {“id”: 3,“title”: “Post-3”,“thumb”: “post3.png”},    
  {“id”: 4,“title”: “Post-4”,“thumb”: “post4.png”},    
  {“id”: 5,“title”: “Post-5”,“thumb”: “post5.png”}
]
```

#### `OrderArray`:

```
[3, 5, 2, 4, 1]
```

#### I need the result to be:

```
[
  {“id”: 3,“title”: “Post-3”,“thumb”: “post3.png”},    
  {“id”: 5,“title”: “Post-5”,“thumb”: “post5.png”},    
  {“id”: 2,“title”: “Post-2”,“thumb”: “post2.png”},    
  {“id”: 4,“title”: “Post-4”,“thumb”: “post4.png”},    
  {“id”: 1,“title”: “Post-1”,“thumb”: “post1.png”},
]
```

Hope I’ll find someone to help, I tried a lot without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution is:**

```js
@Pipe({name: “sortBy”})
export class SortPipe {
transform(array: Array, args: string): Array {
// OrderArray
let sequence = [3, 5, 2, 4, 1];
if (array !== undefined) {
array.sort( function (a, b) {
var A = a[args], B = b[args];

  if (sequence.indexOf(A) < sequence.indexOf(B)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
  
});
}
console.log(array);
return array;
}
}
```